# Cartesian join of two arrays

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to use a for next loop to iterate through the arrays and combine its strings
I can only get the first array. Don't know how to code to combine with the second one and create the third array using VB.NET. could you help please?

ex:

```
arrLetters() As String = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"}

arrNumbers() As String = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
```

resulting `array(81) = {A1, A2 ...A9, B1, B2...B9, ...I9}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# it would be:

```
from letter in arrLetters
from number in arrNumbers
select letter + number
```

In VB, with the result going in to an array variable:

```
    Dim array = (From letter In arrLetters
                 From number In arrNumbers
                 Select letter + number).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below logic (In C#)

```
    var arrLetters= new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"};
    var arrNumbers = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

    var array = arrLetters.Zip(arrNumbers, (letter, word) => letter + word);
```

Hope this helps :)